# Integrating Arduino code into C++

Tags: visual-c++, dll, serial-port, arduino, led

What library/libraries do I need to add in order to communicate with an Arduino from my desktop Visual C++ application?  At this point, all I really want to do is make an LED flash (write high/low to a pin).  I already have the desktop application going, but would like it to interact with the Arduino.  No, Arduino Uno is not suitable for my case.

**Edit 1** Also: I am using a serial USB COM port to connect to the Arduino.

**Edit 2** While I am programming in Windows, the application will be designed for Windows or Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Arduino side, you can just use the built-in Serial to send and receive data.

In the desktop side, refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385228/serial-port-rs232-communication-with-visual-c-2010), which tells you how you can talk to Serial ports in Visual C++

**EDIT**:

If you are planning to use Java, then you can use the Java Serial port library without any changes to the Arduino code.

Also I would recommend you to use the Android APIs if you want to create an Android app. Using NDK is a real pain and unless you know what you are doing, it will be very tough.

Comment: Another thing, I am coding in Windows, but it will be designed for an Android tablet (probably, though I also want to leave my options open for any OS).  Will I have to add several libraries so it's compatible with multiple OS's, or does anyone know of a library that will do that for me?

Comment: How can you run an app that is created in Windows using Visual C++ run in Android OS? Are you using the Android SDK?

Comment: Using the [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)  I'm also thinking of recoding my C++ into Java.

Answer (score 0):

With the arduino connected as a serial device you can have software in the middle which connects it to a network socket.

If you google it you'll find several free programs that do this.

You could even write this yourself in a higher programming language (python, perl, php etc..) very easily, it's just a handful of lines of code.

Then it's quite painless to connect to the arduino, whether its c++ or javascript.