# how to read a string from a port communication?

Tags: python, c, uart

I am really a beginner, 
I send a string  'hello' from a serial Port communication to my module. For that I use Python and Pyserial.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM4', \
    baudrate= 230400  # open serial port
)

print(ser.name)         # check which port was really used
#ser.write(b'hello\n')     # write a string
#str=ser.readline()

while True:
    print(ser.read(30).decode())
ser.close()             # close ports
```

Now I need to recover that string by using my module  then read it on the communication port by using C language.

I would be very grateful really if you could help me please.

Comment: We won't write the code for you. What have you done so far? Have you done any research on serial communication with C?

Comment: I already did that and i am not waiting for anyone to write  code for me, i just need some idea, however there is no answer and no idea  at  all,

Comment: Why no read it using python? Seems like a fools errand

Comment: I just need to enter my hello then use it in a code c that is  it really, but i don't  find the best way to do that.

Comment: PySerial should use in background some C library so check its source code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serial Port (RS232) communication with Visual C++ 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385228/serial-port-rs232-communication-with-visual-c-2010)